# Remove the first characters of a string in LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need a sample code or syntax to remove the first four characters of a string in LotusScript.
Example...

```
Dim cadena As string
Dim resultado As String
cadena = "ab5/xhrtuv94zer"
resultado = FuncionEliminarLeftCaracter(4, cadena)
Print resultado
```

> resultado:   xhrtuv94zer

Comment: Questions must be asked in English here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LotusScript's  [Mid(yourString, start [, length])](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_MID_FUNCTION.html):

```
resultado = Mid(cadena, 5)
```

Comment: Many Thanks Just what I was looking for :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. As you are new on StackOverflow please have a look at this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/223607. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Mid$() and Len() in the documentation.

And please use English for your future questions.